# Strange Java compilation issue involving cyclic inheritance

Tags: java, eclipse, javac, cyclic

So this will be a long story so I thank you in advance for reading.  Let me start by saying that I've been working with java for more than 15 years and I've been working on this specific project for over 5 years and I'm stumped.

I compile the project on 3 different computers.  I was working on the project in eclipse juno on Computer A and everything was fine so I checked in the code.  Then I checked out the code on Computer B and tried a javac clean build and got a bunch of errors, starting with "cyclic inheritance involving..." and then a bunch of errors such as "cannot find symbol" and there were many of these then it had a couple of these "no suitable method found for" until finally it just wigged out and never even gave me an error total.

So, I've never seen anything like this, and as I said the code was fine earlier in the day on a different computer, so I just fired up eclipse, told it to do a clean build, and everything was fine.  Go back to the terminal and do a javac and it compiled fine.  Whew, I said, it must have just been a glitch.

Then on Computer C, which does a nightly build, it gave the same errors as Computer B (note that Computer B is a mac and Computer C is rhel, but both were running jdk1.7u15).  So now I realize it isn't a glitch, but what to do?

I go and look at the code and I'm certain there is no cyclic inheritance and what it says it can't find the symbol for is sitting right where it is supposed to be.  I investigate a bit and find out that eclipse uses an internal compiler so this would explain the disparity between compilations, but it doesn't explain why they are giving wildly different results on the same code base.

Out of ideas, and hoping there is something weird with the update 15, I update Computer B to jdk1.7u51 but unfortunately it is giving the same errors.

I realize without seeing the compiler output (which is really not much more interesting than I described), or more importantly, not seeing the actual code there isn't much you can help with.  But assuming I'm telling the truth, that there is no cyclic inheritance, there are no missing symbols, and eclipse compiles the code fine when javac rejects it, does anyone have a suggestion of what I could try now?

My next thought is to update eclipse, but assuming it still compiles fine there, what to do next?

Thanks again for reading!

Comment: "not seeing the actual code there isn't much you can help with" - absolutely right. So you should reduce the problem to a bare minimum example which still reproduces the example, change any sensitive names, and post that code. It sounds like you can consistently reproduce the problem, so you should be able to remove bits of it at a time fairly easily.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Good suggestion to break it apart. But I guess my point was I'm not necessarily asking for help with my specific problem, but more about how could this huge difference even happen, and how to go about dealing with that.  But again, thanks, I may be able to remove a file or two and start adding back.  Great suggestion.

Comment: Given that it's happening on two computers, it's probably a code error that you haven't spotted yet - but there's not a lot more we can say without seeing any code.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Right, I appreciate that you can't help with the code as I haven't provided anything, I'm more looking for an explanation how one compiler can say something is horribly wrong yet another can say it is perfectly fine.  Sorry for not being clear on what I'm asking.

Comment: The answer to that is usually "Some subtle difference between compilers" - this wouldn't be the first difference between Javac and Eclipse. It's harder to work out what's going on when you've got the same version of the same compiler on two computers and *still* you see a difference.

Comment: Could you be having different class paths on the different machines and some library/class in the class path causing a circluar relationship to happen or not happen?  Maybe in combination with an `import something.*` causing name clashes?